# "the" in "Algebra, arithmetic, ... are <the> branches of mathematics." and "Algebra, arithmetic, ... are <the> branches mathematics has."

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, articles, definite-article, zero-article

[learnersdictionary.com](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/mathematics):
**(1a)** *Algebra, arithmetic, calculus, geometry, and trigonometry are branches of mathematics*.
I would like to know what role the presenсe and the absence of "the" before "branches" plays.

my variant:
**(1b)** *Algebra, arithmetic, calculus, geometry, and trigonometry are **the** branches of mathematics*.

What is the difference between (1a) and (1b)?

---

Also I would like to know whether something will change if I replace "*of mathematics*" with "*mathematics has*".

**(2a)** *Algebra, arithmetic, calculus, geometry, and trigonometry are branches mathematics has*.
Does the absence of "the" in (2a) have the same meaning as in (1a)?
If not, then why not?

**(2b)** *Algebra, arithmetic, calculus, geometry, and trigonometry are **the** branches mathematics has*.
Does the presence of "the" in (2b) have the same meaning as in (1b)?
If not, then why not?

Comment: _[The] branches mathematics has_ is not at all idiomatic. Mathematics isn't a tree with literal branches on it! These 'branches' are sections it can be divided into.

Answer (score 4):

*Are **the*** is exhaustive: *John, Paul, George, and Ringo are **the** Beatles* means that someone is a Beatle if and only if they are one of the four people listed. By contrast, *John and Paul are Beatles* asserts something about the two musicians but does not constitute a complete enumeration of all the Beatles.

Comment: That's the most likely interpretation given the lack of context. You also could use "the branches" to refer to any particular group of branches. Such as: "We offer tuition in three branches of mathematics and two sciences. Algebra, arithmetic, and calculus are the branches of mathematics."

Comment: @StuartF, “…are the branches of mathematics [**in which we offer tuition**].”